# Extending weak stationarity to higher orders

Tags: time-series, stationarity, stochastic-processes

I have many (several thousand) statistically independent time series of the same stochastic process and want to test for stationarity. Due to the large sample size I can easily calculate many statistical measures: There are no obvious trends, constant mean, the autocorrelations only depend on time-differences and the power-spectrum does not vary over time. Thus, I conclude that the process is weakly stationary.

Now I want to go a step further and have a look at stationarity regarding higher orders, however am not sure what a good approach could be. Could you please give me some suggestions for this?

Best regards